# После того как задал вопрос или ответил на него белый экран

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Сайт на WordPress. Подключил плагин DW Question Answer для вопросов и ответов, но когда задал вопрос перенаправляет на белую страницу с таким же url, как у страницы, откуда задается вопрос. Такая же проблема при ответе на вопрос. Может кто знает, как решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Переустанови плагин с удалением данных старых. Я сейчас установил его, работает замечательно. Значит либо с темой твоей не хочет дружить, либо установился не правильно.